# CRC CMD18 SD Card

Tags: sd-card

I'm try to read SDHC card with SPI and a DSP.

I succeed to read a lot of information (capacity, some other informations) using CMD17 command.

Now I want to use CMD18 command (READ_MULTIPLE_BLOCK), because I want to read 2 sectors (2 * 512 bytes). I put all the values in a buffer.

When I read it, there are 4 bytes (when I'm using a 4GB Class 4 or 10 bytes when I'm using a 4GB Class 10) between the 2 sectors which are not on the card (I read the 2 sectors with HxD software). What are these values?

This is an example with a 4GB Class 4:

Buffer values :

```
buffer[511] = 68    **// Good value**
buffer[512] = 143   // Bad value
buffer[513] = 178   // Bad value
buffer[514] = 255   // Bad value
buffer[515] = 254   // Bad value
buffer[516] = 48    **// Good value**
```

Real values readed with HxD

```
buffer[511] = 68    **// Good value**
buffer[512] = 48    **// Good value**
buffer[513] = 54    **// Good value**
buffer[514] = 48    **// Good value**
buffer[515] = 52    **// Good value**
buffer[516] = 69    **// Good value**
```

I don't send CRC (0xFF), does the problem from that?

Thank you for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

> buffer[512] = 143   // Bad value
>
> buffer[513] = 178   // Bad value

These two bytes are CRC for 512-byte block. Can be not used, but can not be rejected from received stream.

> buffer[514] = 255   // Bad value

Card pre-charge next block, you will get random quantity (include zero) of 255's each time. (Depends of SPI speed and card speed)

> buffer[515] = 254   // Bad value

Card is ready to stream next data block. You should awaiting for 254, then you know the following data will be correct. In fact, even before first block of data, you should also wait/get these 255...255, 254.